# How to initialize a tuple of lists to columns of an existing DataFrame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a function which takes the text as input and returns a tuple of lists. I want to convert the tuple into columns of an existing DataFrame.

```
def func(text):
    // some code //
    return (tuple)
```

The tuple is in this format:

```
(['1','2','3'],['abc','def','efg'])
```

I tried doing

```
df[['col1','col2']] = df.col_text.apply(func)
```

But it is throwing an error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I want the output as below:

```
df
       col1           col2
0   [1, 2, 3]   [abc, def, efg]
```

Please let me know the correct and efficient way of doing it.

Comment: "I want to initialize the values of the tuple to existing columns of DataFrame." What *precisely* does this mean? Can you show us with *desired output*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert output to `Series` if need columns of `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_text':range(5)})

def func(text):
    a = (['1','2','3'],['abc','def','efg'])
    return pd.Series(a)

df[['col1','col2']] = df.col_text.apply(func)
print (df)
   col_text       col1             col2
0         0  [1, 2, 3]  [abc, def, efg]
1         1  [1, 2, 3]  [abc, def, efg]
2         2  [1, 2, 3]  [abc, def, efg]
3         3  [1, 2, 3]  [abc, def, efg]
4         4  [1, 2, 3]  [abc, def, efg]
```